# Make User Control Button as default on Enter key press

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot set a DefaultButton on a usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325024/cannot-set-a-defaultbutton-on-a-usercontrol)

I want to Make User Control Button as default on Enter key press. I have a `Default.aspx` page which has a `Login.ascx` user control mounted. On Enter key press i want the Submit button in `Login.ascx` is pressed.

Please help

TIA

Comment: Similar question [Cannot set a DefaultButton on a usercontrol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325024/cannot-set-a-defaultbutton-on-a-usercontrol). Also have a look at [Default Button on a User Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36648/Default-Button-on-a-User-Control)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            $('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
        }
    });
</script>